# How to get the time elapsed in seconds between two timestamps in dql?

Tags: sql, symfony, dql

I'm using Symfony and Doctrine. I'd like to get the time elapsed between two timestamps. Here is a portion of my query (both a.date and q.date are type: timestamp):

```
$qb->select('a.date - q.date AS elapsed_time');
```

This gives a numerical result, but I can't tell what the units are. 9 seconds gave me 49, and 60 seconds gave me 99; I can't make sense of that.

I tried this too:

```
$qb->select('DATE_DIFF(a.date,  q.date) AS elapsed_time');
```

This works, but gives the result in days. I really need minutes or seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) instead. try this:

```
$qb->select('(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(q.date)) AS elapsed_time');
```

Comment: Got an error: "Expected known function, got 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP'"

Comment: @billyhafiz it is because doctrine has no built-in UNIX_TIMESTAMP function. you need to switch to sql or create user defined function UNIX_TIMESTAMP http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language

Comment: I got this to work with: https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the function DATE_FORMAT.

```
$qb->select(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_DIFF(a.date,  q.date), '%s') AS elapsed_time);
```

Try this. I dont have a mysql console now, but i think it would work.

Comment: Got an error: "Expected known function, got 'DATE_FORMAT'"